# SQL query to fetch data of a particular user, from three tables

Tags: php, mysqli

First is a `user` table, second a `places` table and third a `favorites` table (having two fk, one from user and another from places). I want to get all the favorite places of one user, how do I do that?

I tried to play around with joins but what I don't know is how to get data of a particular user.

```
    $qry =
    "SELECT places.place_id , places.db_image ,places.description from places
    inner join favorites on places.place_id = favorites.place_id
    inner join user on user.id = favorites.user_id
    ";

    $query=mysqli_query($con ,$qry);  
    $return_arr = array();
```

Comment: where user_id = 123

Comment: what I actually meant to ask is from this last line because the id is gonna be in some variable, for example $id where should I put it in the query?

Comment: will this work ? join user on user.$id=favorites.user_id? @UlliSchmid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = sprintf(
'SELECT
  p.place_id,
  p.db_image,
  p.description
FROM
  places p INNER JOIN
  favorites f ON p.place_id = f.place_id INNER JOIN
  user u ON u.id = f.user_id
WHERE
  u.id = %d'
, $userId);
```

or if you want simply select all columns from places

```
SELECT
  p.*
FROM
  places p INNER JOIN
  favorites f ON p.place_id = f.place_id INNER JOIN
  user u ON u.id = f.user_id
WHERE
  u.id = %d
```

It is better to use prepared statements, but if you are not familiar with them, this is good enough.